# python: how to tell if a link redirects to another?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of urls, but many of them are outdated which redirect to their homepage or some other page in their domain. I want to filter out these urls from my list. Using `requests`, how can I filter out urls that do not open in the locations they were intended to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the [response history](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.history). **Note**: not all sites use redirects to show you another page.

```
>>> r = requests.head('http://github.com', allow_redirects=True)
>>> r.url
'https://github.com/'
>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

You can also prevent redirects and check if the response `status_code` indicates, see [this example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history):

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com', allow_redirects=False)
>>> r.status_code
301
>>> r.history
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I am using in my project: http://www.elfinite.com/

```
def get_last_redirected_url(self, url):
    """
    """
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.history:
            # Request was redirected
            return response.url
        else:
            # Request was not redirected"
            return url
    except Exception as e:
        return False
        pass
```